# Drupal Images Slideshow

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views

I'm making a website in drupal 7 and need some help.
I created a content type called Itenary where user will upload information and five images.
The images I have taken as Image1, Image2.... Image5 as fields of type image pf the itenary content type.

Now I wish to show these images as something like [this](http://slidesjs.com/)

So I go to the views module -> add new view
Now when I had tried this before, I had selected

> Show *content* of type *itenary*

And it didn't work as I hoped.

So this time, I chose

> Show *File* of type *Image*

I hope this is the right option for my need.
Then I went to create a block, gave it a name.

Now my dilema is how do I bring those fields of Image1 Image2 .. Image5 into this block ?
The fields it shows by default are related to files and not the field of my content type.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the following steps checked.

1- Try to download [jQuery cycle plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/download.html).

2- Create a folder a new folder `sites/all/libraries/jquery.cycle` and place `jquery.cycle.all.js` file inside it.

3- Go and test the results :).

Hope this works... Muhammad.

Comment: All those steps checked. Actually the same settings are working for another view with a different type of node as the field. But this one somehow isnt. Still just as shown in the screenshot

Comment: Can you give me a url to the web page?! -Muhammad.

Comment: sure. We are basically making itenary(proposal) for some industrial visits. So the body will contain details of the trip and I need to show images of the trip on that block. (http://drupal7.lafungaa.in/industrial-visits/second-trial) You could also see the I.V Link on the home page where I have used the cycle plugin to cycle through multiple itenaries, somehow, its not working with images WITHIN the itenary